# How to set up global styling for private routes in React

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm facing a challenge in importing a global CSS for all components within my private route. The issue is that this CSS is also affecting the login screen. Initially, upon entering the login screen, the CSS isn't applied, but after logging in, accessing the private route, and then returning to the login page, I notice that the CSS from the private page is still present. I'm unsure whether the problem stems from how I've configured the routes with the authentication middleware, the conditional import I'm using for the CSS, or the Navigate method, which doesn't seem to reset the CSS. I've tried creating a Layout component that takes an Outlet and importing the CSS there, but even then, the style persists on the login page.

Sorry if the issue is too simple, I'm just starting with React.

How I'm configuring my routes:

```js
const RoutesApp = () => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        {}
          <Route path="/" element={<AuthProvider><RequireAuth /></AuthProvider>}>
            <Route path="home" element={<Home />} />
          </Route>
        <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
        <Route path="*" element={<NotFound />} />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
};
```

How the requireAuth middleware works:

```js
export const RequireAuth = () => {
  
  const location = useLocation()
  const auth = useAuth()
  
  if (auth.user === undefined) { return <LoadScreen /> }
  if(auth.user){
    import('@styles/Privates/root.css'); // global private style
    return <Outlet />
  }
  
  return <Navigate to="/login" replace state={{from: location}} />
}
```

How I perform logout:

```js
const signout = () => {
    setUser(null);
    setToken("");
};

<C.Logout onClick={() => [signout(), navigate("/")]}>Logout</C.Logout>
```

Comment: CSS styles are globally applied. You'll just need to scope your rules using classes and id attributes.

Comment: How would that be done? I'm improving my skills in React, and I'm not sure how that could solve the problem.

Comment: You can accomplish this using specific `className` and `id` props/attributes in your JSX, and match them with your CSS selectors.